# Не получается выбрать frame из frameset вложенного в iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Есть такая структура фреймов:

```
<iframe id="Edit" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="/PortalGrid.aspx?PortalID=1" name="Edit" height="100%" width="100%" onload="EditIframe_OnLoad();">
    <frameset id="FS" style="margin-top: -2px" class="horizontalAlign" rows="0, 100%" frameborder="1" border="2" bordercolor="#A0A0A0" onload="AddBut(undefined, undefined, true, false)">
        <frame name="MainFrame" id="MainFrame" src="BlankPage.htm">
        <frame name="SecFrame" id="SecFrame" src="BlankPage.htm">
    </frameset>
</iframe>
```

Пытаюсь выполнить переход в фрейм SecFrame, используя такой код:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('Edit.SecFrame')
```

Но постоянно ловлю NoSuchFrameException.
Уже пытался и по xpath переход делать и явное и неявное ожидание выставлять, не помогает, SecFrame не находится.

Comment: Я в этом не сильно разбираюсь, но может нужно всё-таки как-то указывать, что SecFrame находится в frameset.FS ?

Comment: попробуйте driver.switch_to.frame('#Edit.SecFrame'), так как Edit это ID

Comment: @MrMorgan вроде как frameset в selenium'e надо указывать только если путь по xpath, читал это на каком-то форуме

Comment: @Денис не # точно нужна, это не jquery, немного свой синтаксис
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге отработал корректно такой код:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('Edit')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//frameset/frame")))
driver.switch_to.frame('SecFrame')
```